# how to read xmlnode and inner ChildNodes and update from input type text?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have an xml file like this...

```
<AnimationPackage>
<condition>
<name>Some Condition 0</name>
<url>http://www.google.com.pk</url>
<rehab>
  <name>Some rehab 0</name>
  <url>http://www.youtube.com</url>
</rehab>
<rehab>
  <name>Some rehab 1</name>
  <url>http://www.youtube.com</url>
</rehab>
<rehab>
  <name>Some rehab 2</name>
  <url>http://www.youtube.com</url>
</rehab>
</condition>
<condition>
<name>Some Condition 1</name>
<url>http://www.google.com.pk</url>
<rehab>
  <name>Some rehab 0</name>
  <url>http://www.youtube.com</url>
</rehab>
<rehab>
  <name>Some rehab 1</name>
  <url>http://www.youtube.com</url>
</rehab>
```

how to count the tags name also like Atfirst `<Conditions>` then `<rehab>` For that condtions
and then inner text from the `<rehab>` tags from `<name>` and `<url>` tag.
I tried this but after first read its not working.. any help plz.

```
XmlDocument readDoc = new XmlDocument();
readDoc.Load(MapPath("JkGroups.xml"));
conditions = readDoc.SelectNodes("AnimationPackage/condition").Count;
rehab = readDoc.SelectNodes("AnimationPackage/condition/rehab").Count;
lblApptitle.Text = dt.Rows[0]["packageName"].ToString();
XmlNodeList nodeListName = readDoc.SelectNodes("AnimationPackage/condition/rehab/name");
XmlNodeList nodeListUrl = readDoc.SelectNodes("AnimationPackage/condition/rehab/url");
for (rehabCount = 0; rehabCount < rehab; rehabCount++)
{
    rehabNodeName = nodeListName[0].ChildNodes[rehabCount].InnerText;
    rehabNodeUrl = nodeListUrl[0].ChildNodes[rehabCount].InnerText;
    rehabtr += "<tr><td style='width: 106px;padding-left: 20px;' >Rehab title</td><td>"
                                      + "<input type='text' value='" + rehabNodeName + "' id='txtRehabSupportTitle" + rehabCount + "' runat='server' /></td><td>"
                                      + "<input type='text' value='" + rehabNodeUrl + "' id='txtRehabSupportURL" + rehabCount + "' runat='server' /></td></tr>";
}
string rehabBody = "<table id='tblRehab'>" + rehabtr + "<tr><td></td><td></td><td><p>Type support product buy URL</p></td></tr><tr>"
                            + "<td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>";
```

there is some thing code missing but I just want to help in xml..

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("c://test.xml");
        var animationPackage = doc.Descendants("AnimationPackage");
        int count = 0;
        foreach (XElement condition in animationPackage.Descendants("condition"))
        {
            count++;
            String name = condition.Element("name").Value;
        }
        //print count . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use more linq features and get count in one expression:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\test.xml");
int rehabCount = doc.Root.Descendants()
.Where(x => x.Name == "rehab").Count(); // 5

 var rehabValues = doc.Root.Descendants("rehab")
 .Elements().Select(tag => tag.Value);
```

results:

rehabCount: `5`

rehabValues:

`IEnumerable<String>` (10 items):

```
Some rehab 0

http://www.youtube.com

Some rehab 1

http://www.youtube.com

Some rehab 2

http://www.youtube.com

Some rehab 0

http://www.youtube.com

Some rehab 1

http://www.youtube.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(......);
var result = xDoc.Descendants("condition")
                .Select(c => new {
                    Name = c.Element("name").Value,
                    Rehabs = c.Descendants("rehab")
                              .Select(r=>new {
                                    Name = r.Element("name").Value,
                                    Url = r.Element("url").Value
                              })
                              .ToArray()

                })
                .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine("Condition#: " + result.Length);
foreach (var cond in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\tCondition[" + cond.Name + "]: " + cond.Rehabs.Length);
    foreach (var rehab in cond.Rehabs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t\t"+ rehab.Name + " , " + rehab.Url);
    }
}
```